# Conky manager 2 not working with Ubuntu Mate 21.10

Tags: conky

Just installed new Ubuntu 21.10. Wanted to have some conky widgets but cannot display them. I'm using;

Ubuntu MATE 21.10 x86_64,
conky 1.11.6,
conky manager 2.73

I can only display the ugly default conky but cannot display others such as Gotham etc.

Here is more information regarding my system;

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.10 x86_64
Host: 80LY Lenovo FLEX 3-1130
Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic
Shell: bash 5.1.8
Mono 13
CPU: Intel Celeron N3050 (2) @ 2.160
GPU: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Proc
Memory: 1509MiB / 3836MiB

conky 1.11.6 compiled 2020-08-17 for Linux x86_64

Compiled in features:

System config file: /etc/conky/conky.conf
Package library path: /usr/lib/conky

General:

- math
- hddtemp
- portmon
- IPv6
- IRC
- Curl
- RSS
- ICal
- iconv
- Weather (METAR)
- wireless
- support for IBM/Lenovo notebooks
- nvidia
- builtin default configuration
- old configuration syntax
- Imlib2
- OSS mixer support
- apcupsd
- iostats
- ncurses
- Internationalization support
- PulseAudio

Lua bindings:

- Cairo
- Imlib2
- RSVG
  X11:
- Xdamage extension
- Xinerama extension (virtual display)
- Xshape extension (click through)
- XDBE (double buffer extension)
- Xft
- ARGB visual
- Own window

Music detection:

- Audacious
- CMUS
- MPD
- MOC
- XMMS2

Default values:

- Netdevice: eno1
- Local configfile: $HOME/.conkyrc
- Localedir: /usr/share/locale
- Maximum netdevices: 256
- Maximum text size: 16384
- Size text buffer: 256

Can someone help?

Thank you in advance.

Frank

Comment: What does can not display them mean? What errors? What steps are you doing to try and display them?

Comment: The regular ugly black conky displays on desktop. Not the ones on the Conky Manager. They are not displayed when I click on the Gotham.

Comment: Here is more information regarding my situation;

Comment: Have you converted your older conky config files to the newer syntax?